# How do I get vile powder?

Tags: terraria-console

Do you buy vile powder or is it an enemy drop or do you craft it? Please help btw im on ps3 terraria if that changes the recipe or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft it from Vile Mushrooms or you can buy it from the Dryad during a blood moon.

Comment: Thanks! I can now kill EoW :) wait how do I delete this post?

Comment: @crusher71 You don't have to delete the question, if this answer is correct then accept it and upvote so if somebody has your same problem here there will be the solution.

Comment: i dont have 15 rep to vote? help i just joined like 1 hour ago now idea what im doing. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can buy the vile powder anytime from the dryad(boss beaten required)or you can craft it using

1vile mushroom(makes 5 at a time)

this requires an alchemy station/bottle on a table/crafting table